# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT with -ve values

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an option to make MySQL's Group_Concat function with large database, that is exceeding the limit of grouped results ?

Consider the following example from my source table:

```
Id, question, mark
10, 3, -10
10, 4, 0
10, 5, 2
10, 8, 1
```

When I query on the selection table for rank calcultaion with GROUP_CONCAT, I get the following for large table:

```
Id, question, mark ,rank
10, 5, 2 ,1
10, 8, 1 ,2
10, 3, -10 ,0
10, 4, 0 ,0
```

I would like to get the following:

```
Id, question, mark ,rank
10, 5, 2 ,1
10, 8, 1 ,2
10, 4, 0 ,3
10, 3, -10 ,4
```

For reference, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT  *,FIND_IN_SET( mark , (    
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( mark 
        ORDER BY mark DESC ) 
        FROM exam_score )
        ) AS rank
        FROM exam_score
        ORDER BY rank asc
```

This query is working with small number of record, My database table with 32,000 rows and its not showing the correct rank of users .

Comment: I'm a bit confused here - I have created your table & run your query & get your expected result.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80ab8/2

Comment: am also wondering , the actual query is rendering 32447 records. Its coming perfectly on small table . the same is not geving the exact rank . Why its not poulating . its coming rank zero only

Comment: Some extra data & expected results would help - as the information provided so far gives your expected result. If you can find a failing data set, create an sql fiddle.

Comment: this is  happening in the query after execution  http://prntscr.com/bgnr95  sql fiddle is not working properly

Comment: I find out the issue is that , the GROUP_CONCAT not querying the all result is excludes some results

Comment: The group_concat limit is the issue of my query.. how can increase the limit of the group concat result

Comment: You could try getting only the distinct marks using _"... GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT mark ..."_

Comment: Thank you so much PaulF, this one is solved my issue. Put it as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are likely to be repeated values for "mark" in the 32447 records and FIND_IN_SET will find the first instance, meaning the 2nd, 3rd etc are not required - you can omit the repeated values using DISTINCT in the GROUP_CONCAT.

```
SELECT  *,FIND_IN_SET( mark , (    
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT mark 
    ORDER BY mark DESC ) 
    FROM exam_score )
    ) AS rank
    FROM exam_score
    ORDER BY rank asc
```